# Using IValueConverter Class to change Background of a textBox

Tags: c#

Hello i have a class to change the background color of a textbox depending off its Text.
if the text is null then its yellow otherwise its transparent. 
But it doesn't work.

```
namespace Contrats_Congeles.Library
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(string),typeof(SolidColorBrush))]
    public class BackgroundConverter_Yellow : IValueConverter
    {
            public Brush YellowBrush { get; set; }
            public Brush TransparentBrush { get; set; }

            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (value==null)
                {
                    return YellowBrush;
                }
                else
                {
                    return TransparentBrush;
                }
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
    }
}
```

Then in then XAML part :

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local1:BackgroundConverter_Yellow x:Key="BackgroundConveter_Yellow"
                                       YellowBrush="Yellow"
                                       TransparentBrush="Transparent"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="CharacterCasing" Value="Upper"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

and in the textbox :

```
 <TextBox x:Name="PdsNetTxtBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                         PreviewKeyDown="PdsNetTxtBox_PreviewKeyDown"
                         Background="{Binding Path=Source,
                    Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConveter_Yellow}}"
                         KeyUp="PdsNetTxtBox_KeyUp"/>
```

But nothing changes even if the text of the textbox is empty.
thanks for helping me

Comment: i think if you swap the colors, your textbox will be always yellow!. i suggest you to add another test ->  see my coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error is coming from test value==null: (empty is different from null) and your binding

i suggest you to add the test of the length of the string

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //test the length of string
        if (value == null || value.ToString().Length == 0)
        {
            return YellowBrush;
        }
        else
        {
            return TransparentBrush;
        }
    }
```

Here my binding in TextBox:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="PdsNetTxtBox" 
            Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self},Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConveter_Yellow}}"/>
```

---

### Full sample:

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"                                                                                                                                              
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"                                                                                                         
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"                                                                                                                    
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"                                                                                                              
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"                                                                                                    
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"                                                                                                                                       
        xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:Contrats_Congeles.Library"                                                                                                                    
        mc:Ignorable="d"                                                                                                                                                          
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">                                                                                                                              
    <Window.Resources>                                                                                                                                                            
        <local1:BackgroundConverter_Yellow x:Key="BackgroundConveter_Yellow"                                                                                                      
                                          YellowBrush="Yellow"                                                                                                                    
                                          TransparentBrush="Transparent"/>                                                                                                        
    </Window.Resources>                                                                                                                                                           
    <Grid>                                                                                                                                                                        
        <TextBox x:Name="PdsNetTxtBox"                                                                                                                                            
                Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self},Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConveter_Yellow}}"/>
    </Grid>                                                                                                                                                                       
</Window>
```

Converter.cs:

```
using System;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
using System.Globalization;                                                                            
using System.Windows.Data;                                                                             
using System.Windows.Media;                                                                            

namespace Contrats_Congeles.Library                                                                    
{                                                                                                      
    [ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(SolidColorBrush))]                                         
    public class BackgroundConverter_Yellow : IValueConverter                                          
    {                                                                                                  

        public Brush YellowBrush { get; set; }                                                         
        public Brush TransparentBrush { get; set; }                                                    

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)    
        {                                                                                              

            if (value == null || value.ToString().Length == 0)                                         
            {                                                                                          
                return YellowBrush;                                                                    
            }                                                                                          
            else                                                                                       
            {                                                                                          
                return TransparentBrush;                                                               
            }                                                                                          
        }                                                                                              

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {                                                                                              
            throw new NotImplementedException();                                                       
        }                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                  
}
```

Comment: may be your binding, see mine

Comment: i have put my full sample, its okay

Comment: if this answer helps you, please, dont forget to uvpvote/validate the answer

Answer (score 0):

XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converterns:TextToBackgroundConverter x:Key="TextToBackgroundConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<TextBox Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource TextToBackgroundConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
```

Converter class:

```
public class TextToBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        string stringval = value.ToString();
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringval)) return Brushes.Transparent;
        else return Brushes.Yellow;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
       return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

P.S. Written on mobile

EDIT: You may want to test what the value is when the Text property is empty. Is the 'value' parameter null or string.Empty. If it is string.Empty, you will have to add 'if(value == null) return Binding.DoNothing;' at the beginning of the Convert method